# Searching for dangles with GDAL

Tags: gdal, ogr, topology

I'm in need of listing all features in a linestring layer that have dangles (that is, one or both of its boundaries do not touch another feature). This being done in GDAL/OGR.

What I'm doing is iterating feature by feature, getting the bounding box of it, using that to do a spatial filter so I only select the features close to the one I'm checking, and then doing topology checks between it and the selected features. Something like this:

```
for i in range(n_feats):
    feat = layer.GetFeature(i)
    # get start and end points of feature
    # get bounding box of feature

    layer.SetSpatialFilterRect(bbox[0], bbox[3], bbox[2], bbox[1])
    n_feats_select = layer.GetFeatureCount()
    for dummy_i in range(n_feats_select):
        feat_select = layer.GetNextFeature()
        # check if feature intersects with previously gotten start and end points
        # if they don't, feature has a dangle, do stuff

    layer.SetSpatialFilter(None)
```

Now, this script ***works***, which certainly matters, but it's slow. Specifically, I'm dealing with a layer with about 2 million features, and the spatial filter is hogging a lot of overhead. Specifically, each feature is taking about 10 seconds to process (the filter method alone taking over 9 seconds), thus 2 million features at this pace would take 231 days to process, give or take.

Is there any GDAL method that already does this, or a better algorithm for accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To speed up the algorithm you should use an Rtree. Now you are testing every feature against the other 2 million features, this is really slow. With the Rtree you can test only against the features close to the start and end points.

Check this [snorfalorpagus](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12420/snorfalorpagus) post, so you can see how to use it:

https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/05/12/using-rtree-spatial-indexing-with-ogr/

Comment: I thought of using R-trees, but I had no idea how to go about it. Glad to know there's a library for that already, thanks for the tip! The warm-up testings were very promissing, the construction of the R-tree generates quite the overhead (about 5 minutes), but after that it goes lightning fast. Initial predictions are that it'll take about 47 minutes to go through all 2 million features, quite the gain from the previous 231 days!

Comment: Take care, R-trees are the gis programmer heroine. ;)